# HTTP connection to Sonoff MINI R4

Tags: esp8266wifi

I have a Sonoff MINI R4 that I want to be able to control by sending it commands over HTTP. I have been able to pair it with the eWeLink app on my phone and have used that to connect it to my local network (a Deco M5 mesh). It shows up on the list of clients on the Deco with an assigned IP however when I add this address to my browser I get no response.
What do I need to do to communicate?